# base64 png in python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, base64

How do you encode a png image into base64 using python on Windows?

```
iconfile = open("icon.png")
icondata = iconfile.read()
icondata = base64.b64encode(icondata)
```

The above works fine in Linux and OSX, but on Windows it will encode the first few characters then cut short. Why is this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Open the file in binary mode](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
open("icon.png", "rb")
```

I'm not very familiar with Windows, but I'd imagine what's happening is that the file contains a character (0x1A) that [Windows is interpreting as the end of the file](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+end+of+file+character) (for legacy reasons) when it is opened in text mode.  The other issue is that opening a file in text mode (without the 'b') on Windows will cause line endings to be rewritten, which will generally break binary files where those characters don't actually indicate the end of a line.

Comment: Linus/OSX treat binary and text files the same, while Windows treats carriage return different in text files than it does in binary files. Also, you should click the checkbox next to his answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Just to make this a wee bit clearer, @Miles is saying replace the first file open with: <pre> iconfile = open("icon.png","rb") </pre> then follow with the rest of the commands. The open command by itself (on Windows) doesn't automatically convert to base64. Duh:-)

Answer (score 9):

To augment the answer from Miles, the [first eight bytes in a PNG file](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature) are specially designed:

- 89 - the first byte is a check that
  bit 8 hasn't been stripped
- "PNG" - let someone read that it's a
  PNG format
- 0d 0a - the DOS end-of-line
  indicator, to check if there was
  DOS->unix conversion
- 1a - the DOS end-of-file character,
  to check that the file was opened in
  binary mode
- 0a - unix end-of-line character, to
  check if there was a unix->DOS
  conversion

Your code stops at the 1a, as designed.